# bash overriding a single line in a text file with another while using variables

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

Overview: I am trying to make a script that will take a list of machines and manually update their /etc/shadow files with a new root passwd. I know this isn't the best method but my boss wants this process automated. we are using a application called puppet for 90% of the update but some machines failed the update or can't have puppet installed, hence this dodgy fix.
(sorry for any stupid errors its only my 3rd week using any unix product, I have been a windows admin my whole life)

Issue:
I need to ssh into the PC's update the /etc/shadow file but only change the root user (not all systems have the same users and I don't want to remove any of those users in the process) I have gotten as far as being able to extract the current user in line 1 through ssh, then check if that user is indeed the root user but I am stuck on then updating the /etc/shadow file on the new machine as my boss has asked that the following standards happen.

I can't have any real user interaction in the script, so no manually typing the new passwd.
I am not allowed to have the new passwd displayed anywhere in clear text (inside the script or in another file)

Ok hopefully that's enough info onto the code.

```
root=user

unknown='unknown.txt'

filelines=`cat $unknown`

prod='new-shadow'

ohf='option-one-holding-file'

pel=prod-errorlog


for line in $filelines ; do

echo "Attempting to fix $line please wait"

ssh -oBatchMode=yes -l $user $line "awk '{if (NR==1) print \$0}' /etc/shadow" >> $ohf         

if grep -q "root:" $ohf ; then

echo "root user located updating to produtcion password"

# ** This is the line that doesn't work **
ssh -oBatchMode=yes -l $user $line "sed -i '1s/.*/$prod/' /etc/shadow"

else    

echo "unable to find root user this will require a manual fix this server will be listed in 
the prod-errorlog file"

echo "$line" >> $pel

fi      

done
```

The line in bold the sed line doesn't work I know why it doesn't work but I have no idea how to fix it at all, thank you to anyone who takes the time to look at this, I know the codes a bit of a mess, please forgive me.

Comment: Thank you Etan for fixing up my poor formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace only the first line:

```
"echo '$prod' > /etc/shadow.new;  tail -n +1 /etc/shadow >> /etc/shadow.new; mv -f /etc/shadow.new /etc/shadow"
```

Sorry for my previous wrong argument wrong:  The `'$prod'` part in your script is correct, and is expanded OK.  Yet $prod contains many reserved characters for regular expressions.  Now this new version just create a new file (replacing the first line) and then move/overwrite on to the target one.

Comment: Thank you so much just one small change I made to this (you still did all the hard work so thank you so much) is I changed the echo to a cat as echo was just giving me the path directory and not the info in the file.

Comment: Glad to know it worked.  Yet I admit that I don't really look at what `$prod` means. I though it is the line itself. :-)